MS DI and contravariance
I've got the following code:
interface IActionHandler<in T> where T : IAction
{
    Status Execute(T action);
}

class SoftwareActionHandler : IActionHandler<SoftwareAction>
{
    public Status Execute(SoftwareAction action)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}

There are of course a few more implementations of IActionHandler<>.
Now when it comes to registering them in MS DI how would I go about doing that? Because of contravariance I can't just do:
services.AddSingleton<IActionHandler<IAction>>, SoftwareActionHandler>();


There are various ways to register them. How do you intend to consume them?

"Because of contravariance I can't just do" - and why exactly do you want to do this?

@JohnathanBarclay I was planning to either consume it as a Dictionary<Type, IActionHandler<IAction>> or a IEnumerable<IActionHandler<IAction>>, where the Type in the dictionary would be the T in IActionHandler.

@GuruStron See my comment above but the idea was to register all implementations of IActionHandler<T> to the MS DI under IActionHandler<IAction>> so I can get an IEnumerable<IActionHandler<IAction>> from the MS DI

@cogumel0 as you noticed in the question - you can't do that since they are not IActionHandler<IAction>

@GuruStron well if it had worked as is I wouldn't have asked the question to begin with :)
I know what the problem is, I don't know what I can do to fix it though - hence asking. Any suggestions?

So the type of action will only be known at runtime? You'll need to be writing some reflection to get that to work, or maybe take a look at MediatR.

@cogumel0 First of all you need to decide how you will store and use the handlers and only then think about how you will register it. Possibly creating a marker interface can work for you (i.e. non-generic version of IActionHandler).

I started with IActionHandler.Execute(IAction action) but it's up to each implementation to ensure the type of IAction is what it expects.
This felt like the perfect place for generics, hence IActionHandler<T>.Execute(T). It guarantees type safety and each implementation is not forced to check that it's getting the correct IAction type.
But whereas with IActionHandler.Execute(IAction) I could just inject an Dictionary<Type, IActionHandler>, I can't with IActionHandler<T>.Execute(T) - that's the problem and what I'm trying to achieve.

@cogumel0 you can have both (i.e. IActionHandler and IActionHandler<T>) and use one to store it as collection and another to inject/use as a concrete handler. But without seeing a full codebase it is hard recommend the best course of action. Note that you can wrap the Dictionary<Type, IActionHandler> in some custom type which will expose method like IActionHandler<T> GetHandler<T>() so you will have it typesafe.

@GuruStron write your last suggestion as an answer I'll accept it - for my project probably feels too much work where I can just use a non-generic interface but it does answer the question accurately and may help others!

@cogumel0 will add it later - want to provide some sample code.

@GuruStron pls don't forget your answer :)

@cogumel0 will tackle it in the next few days, thank you for reminding!

This hugely depends on what you are planning to do with those registrations.  If you have some kind of mediator handler factory then you can go with either marker interface (i.e. a non-generic IActionHandler) or just simply an object and encapsulate this in type-safe wrapper factory which will internally store the Dictionary<Type, IActionHandler> (or Dictionary<Type, object>) and use some reflection magic to build this dictionary.
Or with build in DI you can create a simple wrapper over IServiceProvider:
class GenericHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    public Status Execute<T>(T input) => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionHandler<T>>().Execute(input);
}

and usage will be something like the following:
services.AddSingleton<IActionHandler<SoftwareAction>, SoftwareActionHandler>();
services.AddTransient<GenericHandler>(); // maybe introduce and register as interface

// resolve GenericHandler and use it:

GenericHandler handler = ...;

handler.Execute(new SoftwareAction());

